# Custom Prediction from Complex Model (Functional API Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

[image]

Above is my Keras Model built using TF2. I want the prediction only from Right Network to be fed to the Batch normalization layer via Concatenation layer, though the training is done on the network as shown above with two input layers. During prediction, I am feeding only input to the input_5 Layer to get output from the final classification layer. I do not want any contribution from the Left network during prediction.

Possible Solution:
1. Saved the weights of Target_Model, Batch-Norm to Dense Layer weights (made it Sequential), and replaced the Source_Model by an array of zeros of shape (?, 512). 
Created a new model and added these all pieces together to formulate the new model as required for prediction, where Source_Model is replaced with zeros array in order to feed it to Concatenation layer.
Problem: Error while creating zeros array of shape (?, 512), since batch size is not defined.

How can I solve this problem in TF2.x?

Does anyone know any other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be a solution...

```
## define left model
left = Input((33))
xl = Dense(512)(left)
left_model = Model(left, xl)

## define right model
right = Input((10))
xr = Dense(64)(right)
right_model = Model(right, xr)

## define final shared model
concat_inp = Input((576))
x = BatchNormalization()(concat_inp)
out = Dense(1)(x)
combi_model = Model(concat_inp, out)

## combine left and right model
concat = Concatenate()([left_model.output, right_model.output])
## combine branches with final shared model
combi = combi_model(concat)

full_model = Model([left_model.input, right_model.input], combi)

# full_model.fit(...)
```

after fitting the whole model we can extract what we need

```
## replace left branch in fitted model
fake_left_input = Input((512))

## combine fake left branch with right fitted branch 
new_concat = Concatenate()([fake_left_input, right_model.output])
## combine branches with final shared model
new_combi = combi_model(new_concat)

new_full_model = Model([fake_left_input, right_model.input], new_combi)
new_full_model.summary()

X_right_test = np.random.uniform(0,1, (20,10))
X_left_test = np.zeros((len(X_right_test),512)) 
new_full_model([X_left_test, X_right_test])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here at the end you are passing fake input size (np.zeros(20,512)) where you are fixing the batch size, but we don't know the batch size at runtime which would ideally throw concatenation error if batch size produced from right network mismatches with our fixed batch size. Can you also help on this?

Comment: 20 is a random number I choose, I don't see this problem... you can pass every number you want. new_full_model is used to make inference and can encode every array with variable number of samples... the only constrain is that n_sample of zeros match the n_sample of right input. in other words 20 in zeros array is equal to n_sample of the right array

Comment: I made an edit in the final part if you are more confident... don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)